# How many iterations of the while loop must be made in order to locate it?

Tags: arrays, while-loop

**Im having some trouble trying to find out why the correct answer to this question is 4. Could anyone be kind enough to briefly explain why? Thanks in advanced! Here's the question:**

Consider the array a with values as shown:

4, 7, 19, 25, 36, 37, 50, 100, 101, 205, 220, 271, 306, 321

where 4 is a [0] and 321 is a [13] . Suppose that the search method is called with 
first = 0 and last = 13 to locate the key 205. How many iterations of the while loop must be made in order to locate it?

Comment: What did they teach you in terms of search algorithms for ordered items? Here, if you just assume you're going to start at element at 0 and index one at a time until you find the element you want, it will of course be more than 4. So they're looking for an answer that uses a more efficient algorithm, presumably one you've learned in class, or in the text book you're looking at (for example, binary search).

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have to use a binary search here, as the items are sorted.

Given this array

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7]  [8]  [9]  [10] [11] [12] [13]
 4,  7, 19, 25, 36, 37, 50, 100, 101, 205, 220, 271, 306, 321
```

You initialize with:

```
left and right indexes: l = 0, r = 14 (= length of array)
```

Then you need these iterations:

```
m = (l + r) / 2 = (0 + 14) / 2 = 7
[m = 7] = 100 is < 205 ==> l = 7 + 1

m = (l + r) / 2 = (8 + 14) / 2 = 11
[m = 11] = 271 is > 205 ==> r = 11 - 1

m = (l + r) / 2 = (8 + 10) / 2 = 9
[m = 9] = 205 is = 205 ==> result = [9]
```

= 3 iterations!

However, a slight change to the algorithm can change the number of iterations. If you take `r = N-1` instead of `N` as initial value then you get:

```
m = (l + r) / 2 = (0 + 13) / 2 = 6 (integer division)
[m = 6] = 50 is < 205 ==> l = 6 + 1

m = (l + r) / 2 = (7 + 13) / 2 = 10
[m = 10] = 220 is > 205 ==> r = 10 - 1

m = (l + r) / 2 = (7 + 9) / 2 = 8
[m = 8] = 101 is < 205 ==> l = 8 + 1

m = (l + r) / 2 = (9 + 9) / 2 = 9
[m = 9] = 205 is = 205 ==> result = [9]
```

= 4 iterations!

So the result depends on implementation details. Both variants are correct. Take care to choose the appropriate loop condition (I think `l < r` for the first and `l <= r` for the second algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Just go from the last index.

You start with index 13, which the first iteration you go to index 12, on the 4th iteration you are on index 9, which equals to 205.

Comment: pretty simple answer to a very basic question... :)

Comment: If you count index 13 is the first iteration, then index 9 is fifth iteration (13,12,11,10,9), not the fourth.